# how to safely delete a library?

Tags: angular

I need to make a library with a naming convention like "@our/library" .. at first I didnt realize that ng directly can handle that, so I just did the following:

```
ng new our-library --create-application=false
cd library
ng g library library
ng g application demo
```

after the satisfaction of importing in my demo app directly from my build, I tried `ng g library @our/library` and it worked! I can directly import from '@our/library' after a build! this is crazy :) but, there are changes, like to tsconfig at least I think, that relate to the libraries that ng generates. How do I delete the first library I created?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no command to remove a Library in the CLI, so you need to do it manually.

You need to delete the project from the `angular.json` file by removing the property with the library name from the `projects` value. Here is just the relevant part of the `project.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      ...
    },
    "library": { // delete this entry to remove the library
      ...
    },
    "@our/library": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "demo"
}
```

In the `tsconfig.json` file, you will find an entry with the library name in the `paths` property inside the `compilerOptions`. You also delete this entry and you are ok. Here is the relevant information from `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "library": [ // delete this entry to remove the library
        "./dist/library/library",
        "./dist/library"
      ],
      "@our/library": [
        "./dist/our/library/library",
        "./dist/our/library"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

After these changes, you can also delete the files in the projects folder and your library is removed.